# Advanced Custom Fields: querying posts filtered by custom field values

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to query my CPT posts based on sub custom field values as in example 5 on
[this tutorial](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/).

My CPT (named “trip”) has a repeater field called “departure_date”, which has a sub field called “departure_day”:

```
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'departure_date'", "meta_key LIKE 'departure_date'", $where);
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'departure_day',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);
$get_trips_date = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $get_trips_date->have_posts() ):
    while ( $get_trips_date->have_posts() ) : $get_trips_date->the_post();
        if( get_field('departure_date') ) {
            while( has_sub_field('departure_day') ) { 
                echo get_sub_field('departure_day');
            }
        }
    endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Although sub field “departure_day” is populated for all posts, this code returns nothing. Why?

Comment: i may be wrong on this but i dont think this filter is called for wp_query. It is for get_posts. But try passing `'suppress_filters'=>false` in your $args. You might get lucky!

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. Also the code comes from the plugin devs and they're using wp_query() so I am just doing the same.

Comment: var_dump $where .... you need to make sure you have the correct phrase to change. It seems wp_query does run the filter. See the key name in the query, you change this to like departure_date. also you say at the end, that posts are being returned?

Comment: Thanks, var_dump($where) displays this: string(218) " AND wp_15_posts.post_type = 'trip' AND (wp_15_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_15_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_15_postmeta.meta_key = 'departure_day' AND CAST(wp_15_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) > '0') )". Not sure what to make of it. I'm using a local multisite WP, my project is just one WP site on this multisite setup. Oh and sorry for the confusion, at the end of my question I simply said that in the dashboard I populated the sub field for each post.

Comment: well if you have posts with post meta set as 'departure_day' this will return the posts if the meta key is greater than 0. But my guess is you've saved the dates / days as text? in which case it will always equate to 0 You need to var_dump return values and qet_post_meta() to figure out whats going on here.

Comment: David: nope, dates are saved in "date_picker" format (field type supplied by ACF).

Comment: datepicker is not a db format. What you actually save in the db is a text representation of the date or in unix code a number format. Obviously to do a >= comparision, php will cast '19/11/14' to a number which = 0 What you prob need to do is create a custom meta box for what you want and save the date into a unix date so you can run the compare.

Answer (score 0):

Your  $args should be like this

> `

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'departure_date_%_departure_day',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);
```

`